# How to remove an element from useSprings array by id

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-spring

I'm using react spring's [useSprings](https://react-spring.dev/docs/components/use-springs) hook. My implementation of this hook takes a variable number for the count, and then has an associated configuration.

My hook implementation looks like this:

```
    const [activeTokens, setActiveTokens] = useState([]);
    const [tokenSprings, setTokenSprings] = useSprings(activeTokens.length, (index) => {
            return {
                from: { transform: `translate3d(0px, 0px, 0)`},
                to: async (next) => {
                    var rotate = randomInt(800, 7200);
                    await next({
                        transform: `translate3d(1px, 1px, 0)`,
                        config: { mass: 0.4, tension: 5, friction: 3 },
                    })

                },
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm able to add tokens and render the springs as expected. The issue I'm running into is when I want to remove specific tokens from the DOM. The jsx looks as follows:

```
                    
tokenSprings.map((spring, index) => (
    <animated.div className="text-white text-2xl absolute cursor-pointer" key={index} style={spring}>
        <div onClick={() => handleTokenClick(index)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMoneyBill}></FontAwesomeIcon>
        </div>
    </animated.div >
```

My `handleTokenClick` function looks as follows:

```
function handleTokenClick(tokenId) {
    setActiveTokens(activeTokens => activeTokens.filter(token => token.id !== tokenId));
}
```

This obviously won't work, because I do not have any `token.id` accessible from the `tokenSprings` array. I scoured react spring docs, but I could not find a way to include an id that i'd specify in the `tokenSprings` array for each element, that i can later reference in the jsx.

Is this possible? If not, how is it best to reference the actual `tokenSpring` element which I want to remove from DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does appear to be a mixup in what the argument passed to the `handleTokenClick` callback handler represents.

`handleTokenClick` is coded to take a token id for filtering purposes

```
function handleTokenClick(tokenId) {
  setActiveTokens(activeTokens => activeTokens.filter(
    token => token.id !== tokenId
  ));
}
```

but is passed the mapped array index

```
tokenSprings.map((spring, index) => (
  <animated.div
    className="text-white text-2xl absolute cursor-pointer"
    key={index}
    style={spring}
  >
    <div onClick={() => handleTokenClick(index)}> // <-- index is passed
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMoneyBill} />
    </div>
  </animated.div>
))
```

Unless any of the element objects in the `activeTokens` array happen to have `id` properties that match an array index, it's likely that the filter condition will always evaluate false and no element is removed from the array.

To resolve you should refactor the `handleTokenClick` handler to take an index and filter by the index value.

```
const handleTokenClick = (tokenIndex) {
  setActiveTokens(activeTokens => activeTokens.filter(
    (token, index) => index !== tokenIndex
  ));
}
```

### Setting/Updating a `clicked` property.

Even if you are only updating a nested property of a specific element you necessarily need to create shallow copies of all state, and nested state, that is being updated for React's reconciliation process. Map the previous `activeTokens` array to a new array, and then for the element object you want to update shallow copy it into a new object reference.

```
const handleTokenClick = (tokenIndex) {
  setActiveTokens(activeTokens => activeTokens.map( // <-- new map reference
    (token, index) => index == tokenIndex
      ? {                // <-- new object reference
          ...token,      // <-- shallow copy properties
          clicked: true, // <-- updated property
        }
      : token
  ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input here and my apologies, that was a line of code leftover from trying similar to what you proposed. The reason why filtering by index does not work is because the index doesn't necessarily correspond to the token I want to remove. 

IE: If I have an array of 10 items, and I click the index 2, it will remove the 3rd element in the array. However, I can click the same token again, and it will again remove another token which has now taken place at the 3rd element in the array (index 2)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that allows me to correlate the token ids that I assign so that I may remove the exact token from the `tokenSprings` array..

right now, `tokenSprings` has no identifiers that I may use in `handleTokenClick`. can i do this somehow in my `useSprings` implementation?

Comment: @jamesdlivesinatree I also thought there'd be an issue with using the index, but the `useSpring` demonstration code also uses the index and there didn't appear to be an issue. I didn't see any way to use anything *other than* the index, but that's not to say there isn't any other way to correlate an index to some other data. Would it be possible for you to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could inspect live?

Comment: yes, I'm going to try using `useSpringRef` first. If that doesn't work, I'll comment a codesandbox demo here. Thanks again for helping me out!

Comment: yes, this is indeed the ideal way to use the `clicked` property implementation. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seem you have mistake, in line `<div onClick={() => handleTokenClick(index)}>` you passed index array to param of `handleTokenClick` , but when you define function `function handleTokenClick(tokenId)`  you assigned name for param is `tokenId` instead `index`. I mean you was confused between `tokenId` and `index`

**[Solve]** So, you shoud modify define function `handleTokenClick`:

```
function handleTokenClick(index) {
    const cloneActiveTokens= activeTokens; // clone Active Token
    cloneActiveTokens.splice(index, 1); // remove 1 element from index, array will be mutated
    setActiveTokens(cloneActiveTokens);
}
```

Comment: I commented on the similar answer above. What you noticed was my error indeed, but from a prior implementation using indexes. I'd like to somehow reference the tokenId within the tokenSprings array.

Comment: i read document of useSpring but cannot see how to pass data to useSprings, but you can trick it look like : `const tokenId = activeTokens[index].tokenId`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by adding a `clicked` attribute to my `activeTokens`, and then conditionally adding a `display:none` style if `clicked === true`

```
const handleTokenClick = (tokenIndex) {
    activeTokens[tokenIndex].clicked = true;
    setActiveTokens(activeTokens)
}
```

```
<animated.div className={`text-white text-2xl absolute cursor-pointer ${token.clicked === true ? "hidden" : ""}`} key={token.id} style={tokenSprings[index]}>
    <div onClick={() => handleTokenClick(index)}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMoneyBill}></FontAwesomeIcon>
    </div>
</animated.div >
```

Comment: Careful with this, this implementation directly mutates the `activeTokens` state. Would be better to use function update and map the `activeTokens` array to a new array and then also create a shallow copy of the specific token object *and then* set the `clicked` property. I can add an example to my answer.