# How to Remove an object from a useSprings object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-spring

I'm gonna say first that i'm aware this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75123083/how-to-remove-an-element-from-usesprings-array-by-id).

The solution there didn't help at all, and research on google resolved nothing either.

I have the following `useSprings` object:

```
const fn = (order, down, originalIndex, curIndex, y) => index =>
  down && index === originalIndex
    ? {
        y: curIndex * 100 + y,
        scale: 1.1,
        zIndex: "2",
        shadow: 15,
        immediate: n => n === "y" || n === "zIndex"
      }: {
        y: order.indexOf(index) * 100,
        scale: 1,
        zIndex: "0",
        shadow: 1,
        immediate: false
      };

  const [items, setItems] = useState(["a",'b','c','d']);
 // This represents the item order

const [springs, setSprings] = useSprings(order.length, fn(items.map((_, index) => index))); // Create springs, each corresponds to an item, controlling its transform, scale, etc.
```

Now i want to remove an element from the `springs` array.
That's how i tried to do it (and failed):

````
function deleteFirstItem () {
    setItems(items.filter((_, index) => index !== 1));
    setSprings(order.length, fn(order)); // I've understood I'm supposed to just update the ```items``` array, but it didn't work so I tried to add this line. Still didn't work.
    }
````

The problem is that the function doesn't work and the array `springs` remains the same.

[You can see the full code in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-draggable-list-forked-l3pf2t?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A53%2C41)

Comment: [`useSprings`](https://www.react-spring.dev/docs/components/use-springs) returns `[springs, api]` where `api` has the [methods described here](https://www.react-spring.dev/docs/advanced/spring-ref#methods). It's also worth noting that in your sandbox code, you are calling `setOrder` and expecting an immediate change in the value of `order`. This isn't how hooks work... keep track of the value you set if you need to reuse it on subsequent lines... and... arrays start at `0`. Your "first item" appears to be `1`...

Comment: Ok, that's the first time I've seen someone mentioning this ```api``` while trying to resolve this issue.
Does that mean i need to use useRef for keep tracking the value of ```order```?
But I couldn't understand this ```Controller``` mentioned in the link you provided

Answer (score 0):

*We can try this, first create the new order and and new springs array then, we update the order state with the new order using setOrder and after this we update the springs state by directly passing the new springs array to setSprings.*

```
function deleteFirstItem() {
  const newOrder = order.filter((_, index) => index !== 1);
  setItems(items.filter((_, index) => index !== 1));

  const newSprings = newOrder.map((_, index) => fn(newOrder)(index));

  setOrder(newOrder);
  setSprings(() => newSprings);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the results of this code are exactly as my code: The array ```springs``` remains with 4 object and only the ```order``` and ```items``` states are changed